# Send updates from unbound Flux with Micronaut Websocket endpoint

Tags: websocket, project-reactor, micronaut, reactor-netty

I have a Flux which emits an unbound number of values on an interval.
I need a Websockets endpoint, which emits the values of the Flux when a client connects.

Currently I realized it as follows:

```java
@ServerWebSocket("/updates")
public class UpdateController {
    private Flux<Update> updates;
    
    // ... left out for brevity

    @OnOpen
    public Flux<Update> onOpen(WebSocketSession session) {
        return updates.flatMap(session::send);
    }

    @OnMessage
    public void onMessage(String content) {
        // do nothing
    }

    @OnClose
    public void onClose(WebSocketSession session) {
        // do nothing
    }
}
```

This works, but as soon as the client closes the connection, an exception is thrown.
Makes sense to me, since the `updates` Flux still emits values and session::send
will get called.

But how could I structure my code in a way, that this exception is not thrown? I
have the feeling that I am missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prevent emitting value to the closed session by adding a filter that checks if the session is open before the flatMap call:

```java
@OnOpen
public Flux<String> onOpen(WebSocketSession session) {
    return updates
            .filter(it -> session.isOpen())
            .flatMap(session::send);
}
```

Comment: That's it. Thank you, Szymon! In the meantime I came up with the solution of using takeWhile instead of filter. Both results seem to be comparable.